# Getting the confidence interval for Click through Rates

Tags: machine-learning, probability, confidence-interval, recommender-system

I am trying to  analyse the performance of two algorithms , bascially through click through rate and i have arrived at the following form

```
Algorithm   Day Users   CTR
1            1   100    20
2            1   10     100
```

Now here's where i am confused . From the data above , it looks like `algorithm2` is better than `algorithm 1` , *but how do i account for the number of users*? .

Clearly algorithm 2 had fewer number of users.I believe if i consider the users also into consideration i may be able to provide a confidence interval on the CTR which might make more sense.

Can someone guide me on getting the confidence interval for the CTR?

Comment: In the phrase, "click through rate" , what is meant by the word "rate" ? What I'm getting at is that doesn't the rate already take the number of users into account? Is click through rate essentially, the number of users who "clicked through" divided by the number of users?

Comment: @BradS. It doesnt take into account the number of users , the formula is number_of_clicks/Total_emails_sent

Comment: How is "total emails sent" different from "total number of users" to whom emails were sent?  and how is "number of clicks" different from "number of users who clicked on the link in the email"?  I hope you're not spamming individuals with multiple emails asking them to click on a link (or links) in the email.

Comment: @BradS.one mail may contain n number of recommendations, so its different

Comment: I would think you need to calculate the click rate per person per email, and try to maximize the average. By only looking at the CTR per algorithm, you miss the distribution. Algorithm 2 may not be better per se, but it could be that one really bored person was given an email with algorithm 2 and they're skewing the algorithm average. To get the CTR per person, just calculate the number of clicks/number of emails received per person rather than for the whole group.

Comment: so the idea is essentially, that users in algorithm 2 spend more time (or more clicks) than algorithm 1? If this is the case, I agree with Brett that you should compute the ratio for each user, and then you can compare the modes of the two ratios (or the median). However, if you only look at the expectation, you have to make sure they have equal variance, otherwise this can milead your results again due to skewed distributions with heavy tails.